# kivy event handlers in templates

Tags: python, kivy

have a look the following codes that I consider to have the equal effect:

`main.py` is the same for both version, and it is quite boring:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class MainWidget(Widget):
    def callback(self):
        pass        

class MainApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()⏎
```

the working version of `main.kv` is as follows:

```
MainWidget:
    Button:
        text: "Buttontext"
        on_press: root.callback()
    Button:
        text: "Buttontext"
        on_press: root.callback()
```

I want to repeat that for many Buttons! That's why I thought about a solution looks like this:

```
<TB@Button>:
    text: "Buttontext"
    on_press: root.callback()

MainWidget:
    TB:
    TB:
```

which does not work. I tweaked the example to look like this:

```
<TB@Button>:
    text: "Buttontext"
    on_press: main.callback()

MainWidget:
    id: main
    TB:
    TB:
```

...but that doesn't work either. Is the `template`-feature compatible to my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the resolution of the `root` keyword. In your dyanmic class definition, `root` refers to the class itself, not to any parent it eventually has.

Since you're (presumably) sure the buttons will always be used by being added to the MainWidget, you could use `self.parent` instead of `root`.

Comment: Is there a way to make that work with nested `TB`s? Say, I put all those buttons in a Layout: Then `self.parent` will refer to the layout. Do I have to refer to `self.parent.root` (if that works) or is there a nicer way to do this?

Comment: I just tried self.parent.root, but that did not work. Is there no way to access root of the actual instance? Another idea: Can I give `root` a name in the kivy file, so that I can refer to that name in the following declarations?

Comment: This worked for me but I needed to use self.parent.parent.callback() as the self.parent is the GridLayout.